# Azure IoT Hub and its SDK message overhead

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins

I'm trying to use the Azure IoT Hub to store data sent over MQTT from a sensor, the problem I'm running into is that it is quite a bit slower then I would have expected.

From what I understand I should be able to send 4kb 100 times a second, if I send more then that then IoT Hub will queue up the messages and eventually throttle it to the maximum speed.

That is all fine and good but what I'm scratching my head over is that currently I have been sending a message with a data size of 84 bytes and the device ID in the package is 68 bytes the rest is the overhead that I cant disable, from what I understand if I send a message with IoT hub that is below 4KB it counts as a 4KB message so I assumed that I would get at least 100 messages per second but currently each message takes 0.6 seconds to send.

Anyone have any ideas why my packages are getting so heavily throttled or suggestions what I could do? If I use TLS/SSL connection and a dedicated MQTT broker could I see a speedup?

The goal is to take real data from a physical device and then compare it to simulated data from a online device using IoT Hub to store all the data since it seems to be made for that but with out buying the 2.5k$ a month package the amount of data I can upload from a device just seems so little.

Answer (score 0):

Made a mistake, it is 12 messages from Device to Cloud per second and 1.6 from Cloud to Device per second so what is happening is that I'm hitting the Cloud to Device bottleneck.

Still unsure if there are more optimal ways or if I would get a better results with a dedicated MQTT broker in combination with IoT Hub.